# Memory Management for Obj-C Properties which reference parent node class

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have two classes which refer to each other:

The one class seen below has a property which will hold an array of the second class:

```
@interface MPReportBuilderTableRecord : MPRecord

// NSArray of MPReportBuilderTableColumnRecord objects
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *tableColumns; 

@end
```

The second class however contains a property which equals the "parent node" or the "owner" of this object.

```
@interface MPReportBuilderTableColumnRecord : MPRecord

// Reference to Parent Node/Object
@property (assign) MPReportBuilderTableRecord *parentTable;

@end
```

My questions are:

1. What do you call this concept and relation between child and parent object properties
2. I have encountered some memory leak cycles because of these references. What would be the appropriate memory assignments for the parentTable property?

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using ARC? If you do then the relationship to the parent object should be set as `weak`.

Comment: Will keep that into consideration, currently "this code" isn't using ARC yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GOF Book calls the pattern [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

When using reference counted ownership (no matter ARC or MRC) it's usually best to make the child nodes not point to the parent nodes or make the association weak.

That's what you did by specifying the `parentTable` property to use `assign` semantics. There are no memory issues in the posted code.

Comment: Agreed. Although I think the qualification of "ARC or MRC" is redundant, Objective-C uses reference counts. ARC just simplifies it, but it's still there.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me the chapter or page range for the GOF book. I would love to read about this in more detail.

Comment: @Abizern That's what I wanted to point out. Thanks for making it clear.

Comment: @SeanLarkin The linked wikipedia page has this as the first reference. I don't know if the content is available online.

Answer (score 1):

> What do you call this concept and relation between child and parent object properties

Parent-child relationship.

> I have encountered some memory leak cycles because of these references. What would be the appropriate memory assignments for the parentTable property?

You need to decide whether the parent logically owns the child or vice versa.  I almost always decide the rule "parent owns the child".  Then the parent property of the child should be a weak property (or assign, if not using ARC).